# Get return value from a function in a class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a class for a project called KobbyCloud, it will help me select user data easier.  So what I've done is make a function in the class, and it basically uses PDO to connect in this example here:

```
class KobbyCloud {
  function connect($username, $password) {
    return new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=kobbycloud; charset=utf8", $username, $password);
  }
}
```

So basically, all you have to do to connect is:

```
$kobbycloud = new KobbyCloud();
$kccn = $kobbycloud->("mysql-user", "mysql-pass");
```

This works absolutely fine, in fact I can use normal PDO properties on it even.  Like the `prepare`... If I were to do `$get_user = $kccn->prepare("...SQL...");` it would work fine!

---

But the problem persists when I try to make a function in the class to get the user data.  I don't know what to use for the selector when doing SQL.

```
class KobbyCloud {
  function connect($username, $password) {
    return new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=kobbycloud; charset=utf8", $username, $password);
  }

  function user_data($sel) {
    $get_user = ?????->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=1");
    $get_user->execute();
    return $get_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } 
}
```

You can see where I put the `?????` is where I'm having trouble...  So I thought the solution would be to get the return value from the `function connect(...)` but I don't know how to go about doing that.

---

I'm fairly new to PHP classes, so thanks for any tips or clarification I get about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the connection in your class

```
class KobbyCloud {

    private $connection;

    function connect($username, $password) {
        if ($this->connection === null) {
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=kobbycloud; charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }

    function user_data($sel) {
        $get_user = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=1");
        $get_user->execute();
        return $get_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wow, seems so simple.  All you have to do is save it as a variable then return the variable.  Then you can also use it elsewhere.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Just for having said it: Having a database connection as part of an object's state is usually bad practice, because it creates a fairly tight coupling. :) If you ever want to venture into unit-testing, this will give you a headache.

Comment: Then, having a dedicated method in that class for user_data() is also tight coupling

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pretty much just built a factory class. It helps you with the creation of a PDO object, but is isn't a model for your database connection.

There are two approaches to achieve what you want to do:

1. Instead of returning the PDO object make your class inherit from PDO and then you can just replace any PDO related stuff in your application with your new class. This also allows you to add any additional functions you might want and then inside those functions you have access to the PDO object via `$this`.

   ```
   public class KobbyCloud extends PDO { ... }
   ```
2. Use your class as a utility. In this case it will be completely stateless and you have to provide the PDO object with every method call you do.

   ```
   function user_data(PDO $pdo, $sel) { ... }
   ```

There are also other approaches (like the one shown by Mark), but these are the most straight-forward ones. Overall it seems like you missed the idea behind OOP a little bit, so it might be worth it to dive a little deeper into the topic. The approach you chose doesn't really fit with the whole concept of OOP, which is why you have such a hard time making it work.